How to resolve " Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(String) from the type mw2.TaxCodeService "
Should have mentioned that I am trying to get the W1M1 checkbox value (ticked) to appear in the Tax_Code_2__c field which is a text field. The other methods work, just not with this particular one.
Method below is the overall method used:
private static void setTaxCodeComponentFieldsFromTaxCode2(
    Tax_Code__c taxCode
  ) {
    // Breakdown Tax_Code_2__c into it's component parts
    // This is the reverse of Tax_Code__c formula field

    // 1. Get The Tax Code Prefix FROM Tax_Code_2__c
    // 2. Tax Code Number
    // 3. Tax Code Letter
    taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c = getTaxCodePrefix(taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c);
    taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c = getTaxCodeLetter(taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c);
    taxCode.Tax_Code_Number__c = getTaxCodeNumber(
        taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c,
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Prefix__c,
        taxCode.Tax_Code_Letter__c
    );
    taxCode.W1_M1_X__c = ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c);
}

The method below is the ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2() method :
private static Boolean ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(Tax_Code__c taxCode) {
    taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c.contains(taxCode.W1_M1_X__c);

    if (taxCode.W1_M1_X__c == true) {
        return true;
    } else if (taxCode.W1_M1_X__c == false) {
        return false;
    }

    return Boolean.valueOf(ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(taxCode));
}

I had tried to change the privacy of the method itself from private to  public.
I then tried to add a String to the taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c.contains() section.
I also wanted to take void of the setTaxCodeComponentFieldsFromTaxCode2() method but I didn't want to risk it.
Any solutions and advice would be great.

Is it only me, or does taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c look like a String? The method ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2, what should I say, expects - not Strings, does it?! Apart from that - what is the idea of Boolean.valueOf(ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(taxCode))?!

@FelixvanHove you completely just reminded me to add that into the question section. Yes taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c and ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2 is a Boolean method more or less.

@FelixvanHove the idea of Boolean.valueof(ifW1M1IsInTaxCode2(taxCode)) is to essentially return true or false when it comes to W1M1X as a checkbox being ticked or not

(a) The method expects a Tax_Code__c, but you give it a string (or something). (b) the return value calls the method recursively--stack overflow if you ever managed to hit that line of code, (c) the contains line does nothing, because you don't store the return value from contains. (d) What are the data types for Tax_Code_2__c and W1_M1_X__c?

@sfdcfox the datatypes for Tax_Code_2__c is Text and the datatype for W1_M1_X__c is Checkbox.

If that's true, then isW1M1XIsInTaxCode2 shouldn't compile. I'd expect the method to look more like: static Boolean isW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(String taxCodeString) { return taxCodeString.contains('W1_M1_X'); } or something like that.

@sfdcfox I see what you mean, thank you

I think there's a issue in this line -
taxCode.W1_M1_X__c = ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c);

ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2 function likely expects a complete Tax_Code__c object as input to perform its logic and determine the return value. You're currently passing taxCode.Tax_Code_2__c, which is assumed to be a field within the Tax_Code__c object. For eg,
private static Boolean testMethod(Account acc) {//Some logic}

//and your passing a field of Account (String) other than passing the acc (object)
someotherMethod() {
   Account acc = new Account();
   acc.Name = 'test';
   testMethod(acc.Name);
}

Assuming you want to pass the entire taxCode object to the ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2 function, the corrected line would be:
taxCode.W1_M1_X__c = ifW1M1XIsInTaxCode2(taxCode);

Also please check what is the taxCode.W1_M1_X__c datatype of it, your'e assigning a Boolean value to it.
